# Берет энтити за 7 минут, хотя там 15к записей

Tags: java

У меня есть таблица всего с 15000 записями. Но взятие сущности с базы занимает около 6-7 минут. Для 1 экземпляра.

Стек: spring-boot 2.3.3 hiber 5.4.20final

SQL приводить не буду, там банальный селект всех полей (смотрел по логам хибернейта).

Итак, сущность:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
/*60 полей скрыл, просто стринги и интежеры*/

    @JsonProperty("Employees")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subjectEmployeesId")
    private List<SubjectUsers> Employees;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Supplier")
    private List<Contract> contractSup;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Customer")
    private List<Contract> contractCus;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Supplier")
    private List<ContractAct> contractActSupplier;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Customer")
    private List<ContractAct> contractActCustomer;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Subject")
    private List<ContractActSign> contractActSigns;
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Organizer")
    private List<TrdBuy> contractTrdBuy;
```

Есть 7 @OneToMany маппингов.

Comment: По идее OneToMany должны всё тормозить. Попробуйте их временно закомментировать, например.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб проверю. Скорее всего это и есть OneToMany, но мне даже LazyLoad не помогает. Я без понятия почему.

Comment: Начните с того, что включите sql лог и посмотрите, какие запросы выполняются (все запросы, а не только основной) при загрузке и сколько времени они занимают. Если грузятся данные, которые вам не нужны, и это влияет на время, то нужно это менять. Сколько всего запросов выполняется когда это занимает 6 минут? Сколько занимает каждый запрос? Сколько данных (в мегабайтах) при этом читается из БД? Без этой информации что-то конкретное сказать сложно (если вообще возможно)